# Is there a way to *not* correlate all values in a matrix (and get r-values, and p-values with corrections)?

Tags: r, matrix, correlation, p-value, error-correction

I have two variables with 4 levels each (e.g., A1, A2, A3, A4, B1, B2, B3, B4). I would like to correlate all the A-variables with all of the B-variables, and obtain r-values and p-values (i.e., 16 correlations total). I would also like to adjust my p-values with False Discovery Rate (fdr)).

Normally, I would use `corr.test` (see below) but but this will *also* compute the correlation **between** my A and B variables (e.g., B1 with B2, B1 with B3...), which means that my FDR correction will be more conservative than I would like (i.e., will assume I've computed more than 16 correlations).

**Basically**, how can I use `corr.test` (or a similar function) to get, 1) Pearson Correlations between only some of my variables (not all of my variables), and 2) Compute corrected p-value tests on those correlations. Thank you.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(psych)

#Creating Matrix   
dt <- data.matrix(data, rownames.force = NA) #see below for sample data.

#Using corr.test to get correlations and adjusted p-values
matrix <- corr.test(as.matrix(dt[, -1:-3]), adjust = "fdr")

new_matrix1 <- matrix$r #My correlation ('r') matrix
new_matrix2 <- matrix$p #My FDR-corrected p-value matrix

#sample data
        data <- readr::read_csv("StudyID,Group,Session,A1,A2,A3,A4,B1,B2,B3,B4
    ID1,Control,2,60.15394,121.70584,3.70E+02,3.79E+02,-1.9652,1.73341,0.52618,82.41163
    ID2,Control,2,6.13E+01,159.91384,4.15E+02,6.37E+02,-1.87955,1.99063,1.05859,84.35755
    ID3,Control,2,38.8401466,44.0845579,140.7930682,118.180393,-1.77581,1.54942,-1.96658,69.98878
    ID4,Control,2,83.44192,139.62052,54.67489,168.35044,-1.9226,1.40491,-1.76027,67.05391
    ID5,Control,2,67.85794,108.47434,3.52E+02,3.07E+02,-1.99334,2.3971,-1.76027,69.23536
    ID6,Control,2,60.52657,88.31131,3.10E+02,2.48E+02,-1.9931,1.17814,0.13324,58.69933
    ID7,Control,2,46.8067045,49.9408858,134.2375192,102.8227174,-1.99451,2.69449,-1.23305,61.72975
    ID8,Control,2,51.5625169,64.1753623,203.3134279,274.857598,-1.99718,1.77547,-0.06854,62.49022
    ID9,Control,2,14.58303944,53.4748433,137.608523,181.67666,-1.99481,2.28967,-1.99976,67.50451
    ID10,Control,2,25.9026077,74.0833919,127.5542966,151.9610471,-13.99166,-9.97691,-12.34088,54.04087
    ID11,Control,2,56.182202,65.0797187,125.2569632,124.4980811,-13.99718,-10.36589,-13.76081,55.0675
    ID12,Control,2,33.4045967,51.9653024,124.4222258,155.8207412,-13.99766,-10.46825,-13.75175,62.66764
    ID13,Control,2,49.0317467,82.2806435,108.3708056,98.4456248,-13.9991,-10.47524,-13.96352,49.78162
    ID14,Control,2,47.4924854,78.3363953,106.3392452,132.2831822,-13.99376,-10.47065,-13.81055,48.96265
    ID15,Control,2,49.8489374,74.1534962,161.7199511,207.0637076,-13.994,-10.02833,-13.06022,68.0425
    ID16,Control,2,29.0153,71.49869,242.85308,211.34423,-12.99451,-9.72049,-11.71021,49.38233
    ID17,Control,2,128.53246,180.18814,3.37E+02,4.45E+02,-12.34264,-9.61639,-10.03498,62.49446
    ID18,Control,2,6.73924,41.0098,88.77817,88.29004,-12.99733,-9.68674,-12.87391,52.80611
    ID19,Control,2,4.08955,71.51905,98.85037,72.81613,-12.94114,-9.49024,-12.85528,53.53397")
```

Comment: Thanks for noticing - I forgot to add quotation marks (these have now been added!)